# Constant dynamic image loading with Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, sails.js

Our team is developing a small web/native android application with Sails.js as our server framework.

One functionality requires sending a not-fixed number (between 10-100) of images, think of a comic reader.

I know we can do a single page view and request each image separately, but this seems to create a bottleneck with DB access and authorization of the user.

Is there a way to keep a constant stream of the images loading with the client?

Should I compress/optimize the images for each client?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We could help a lot better if you showed actual client and server code.  Authorizing a user on each incoming request should NOT be an expensive operation.  If it is, then you have a problem with that code.

If you're literally trying to down load 100 images from the server as separate images, that's just going to take 100 requests and you just need to make your server really efficient at serving those 100 requests (caching, really efficient DB, etc...).  You can parallelize the requests in the client so perhaps 10 at a time can be downloading.

In some cases, you can configure things for a client use a sprite where many separate images are combined in one file and the client is smart about displaying pieces of the main image to appear to show lots of separate images.  This is most effective when the groupings of images are known in advantage and can be pre-computed on the server and ready to serve.  If the client is requesting an arbitrary set of images, then a sprite probably won't be practical.

> I know we can do a single page view and request each image separately, but this seems to create a bottleneck with DB access and authorization of the user.

That's how you do it.  You need to make your DB access and authorization very efficient to serve the large number of download queries.

> Is there a way to keep a constant stream of the images loading with the client?

You can code the client to keep 10 requests in flight at any given time so you have some paralellism in your client downloading, but without overloading the server by sending all 100 requests at once.

> Should I compress/optimize the images for each client?

Images should already be compressed.  If they are JPEG or PNG, they will already be compressed.  You can experiment with compression levels to optimize your compression.  Different subject matters can be optimized differently, sometimes achieving very high compression without unduly compromising the image quality (depends entirely upon the image subject matter).

You should certainly make sure your images are sized optimally so you aren't download a higher resolution than your client wants to display.  Downloading a 4k image when you only really need to display a 1k image is obviously a huge waste of bandwidth and download time.